# Dynamic Controls required to load on every Postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

i have dynamically create multiple tab of tabcontainer , each cantain n no's of Question and its Option (option are radiobutton may be 2 to 5) that also dynamic and make radiobutton AutoPostBack=true; 
all this bind in UpdatePanel inside placeholder
created at init event

problem when i check radiobutton the page post back recreate all the dynamic controls after that it point to the method of fire control

pls help me i stake on this

Comment: You create controls in the Init of the page, or the init of Update Panel?

Comment: Please make you question more clear and add your code.

Comment: However, you could try create the control on the init_page and then populating controls with data on load

Answer (score 0):

may be you should load your dynamic control inside the postback back event.

while you click on radio button then again your page_load event calls and the code to create dynamic control is executes.

to avoid re-creation of dynamic control you should create your control inside the postback event.

Sample Code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   // Code to create your dynamic controls.
}
```

If it's not work for you, please give more clarification about your problem with code block.

thanks.